# How can I evenly but randomly distrybute particles in a mesh?

Tags: particles

I'm working on a project and I want particles to create an object together randomly. Something like this:

[image: Example]

But as you can see, it distrybutes the planes randomly but even. There are more of them in the buttom, than in the top.
I tryed to change the seed and I tried to enable *Even Distrybution* in the Emission-Settings of the ParticleSystem but I get the same problem!

This is, what the mesh looks like:

[image: Test]

And here is a part of my ParticleSettings:

[image]

Comment: Under Emit From: Volume check Even Distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the uneven geometry interfering with the distribution of the particles. Add a Remesh modifier just before the Particle System in the modifier stack and, as well as enabling the Even Distribution (as mentioned by @LukeD), ensure to enable Use Modifier Stack. This should result in an even distribution of particles throughout the volume.

Without Remesh :
[image: without remesh]

With Remesh :
[image: with remesh]